# K&R 2.5 solution modification to output location/value of matches between strings

Tags: c, output, c-strings

K&R 2.5 asks: Write the function any(s1,s2), which returns the first location in the string s1 where any character from the string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 contains no characters from s2. (The standard library function strpbrk does the same job but returns a pointer to the location.)

Using the first solution given here (http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_2:Exercise_5), I'd like to modify the test values to output the location of the match(es).

That is, the test value just gives "passed" if everything works all right.  I modified line 127 to output "without match" if there was not a match (and this very simple mod works), but modifying line 142 to display the location/value of the match is not working.  If I just use "leftstr[left]" as the value, I get weird values (L, ', etc.) and if I try to correct using say "(leftstr[left]-'0')" I also get weird values (Korean character, L, ?, etc.)

Ideally I would like to know how to cue up both the position and the value of the match(eS).  FYI I am only at about K&R c. 2.9 and self-studying so the more you can use material from that (early) point forward, or a basic explanation of anything beyond that, the more I would appreciate your answers.

I copied the test driver with the modded lines tagged below.  Thanks in advance.

```
/* test driver */
```

...

```
    for (left = 0; left < numlefts; left++)
    {
        for (right = 0; right < numrights; right++)
        {
            pos = any(leftstr[left], rightstr[right]);
            ptr = strpbrk(leftstr[left], rightstr[right]);

            if (-1 == pos)
            {
                if (ptr != NULL)
                {
                    printf("Test %d/%d failed.\n", left, right);
                    ++failed;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Test %d/%d passed, without match. \n", left, right); //mod
                    ++passed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ptr == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Test %d/%d failed.\n", left, right);
                    ++failed;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ptr - leftstr[left] == pos)
                    {
                        printf("Test %d/%d passed, match at %c \n", left, right,
                                leftstr[left]);  //mod w/ issue
                        ++passed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Test %d/%d failed.\n", left, right);
                        ++failed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal passes %d, fails %d, total tests %d\n", passed, failed,
            passed + failed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What means "cue up"? (Not a native here.)

Comment: Need to see more of your code and variables. `any` takes strings but `any(leftstr[left], rightstr[right]);` seems to be `char`s.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I meant point to / give the value of for "cue up" (Display them / refer to them so they can be displayed)

Comment: the code is kind of long to keep tapping space 4 times in the comment (there must be an easier way, right), but it's all at the first solution in the link above.  the "any" function does take characters, here it is:

Comment: 'code'int any(char s1[], char s2[])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int pos;

  pos = -1;

  for(i = 0; pos == -1 && s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; pos == -1 && s2[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
      if(s2[j] == s1[i])
      {
        pos = i;
      }
    } 
  }

  return pos;
}

Comment: So `any` does NOT take characters (`char`) but takes strings (`char []` or `char *`). And you pass characters in `pos = any(leftstr[left], rightstr[right]);` Turn warnings ON of your compiler.

Comment: You're correct, thanks.  But to restate, my original question was how to get a result that points to the location in the string or character in the string that "matches" between two strings.  Maybe I will try reposting with a clearer explanation and all code.

Comment: Well, first publish correct code and then we can give advice how to do what you want. With correct code it is easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

> If I just use "leftstr[left]" as the value, I get weird values

Of course you may get weird values when you try to print a `char *` (which `leftstr[left]` is, the whole *string s1*) with the conversion specifier `c`.

> modifying line 142 to display the location/value of the match is not working.
>
> ```
>                         printf("Test %d/%d passed, match at %c \n", left, right,
>                                 leftstr[left]);  //mod w/ issue
> ```

This is working:

```
            printf("Test %d/%d passed, match at position %d, value %c\n"
                , left, right, pos, *ptr);  //mod w/o issue
```